# Integrating selenium libraries into Azure Synapse spark pool

Tags: python, apache-spark, selenium-webdriver, azure-synapse

Hy! I need to use the Selenium Python library to extract specific HTML content from certain links. Since my entire pipeline runs on Synapse, does anyone know if it's possible to integrate Selenium into a Synapse Spark pool and how to do it? I require a local Chrome driver to run Selenium.

Should I have some VM as linked services which I will need to integrated into my synapse pipeline or it has another way for solving this problem?